# how to retrieve selected item from ListBox and convert it to string?

Tags: string, listbox

I tried

```
if( ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("test")
{
    //do something
}
```

and

```
if( ListBox.SelectedValue.ToString().Equals("test")
{
    //do something
}
```

none of them gets the selected value or item into string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if that is actual looking of your code there are mistakes. you should add one brace at the end of if statement.

if not i don't see any mistakes at there. But beware if you use SelectedItem.toString(). That is not giving you the value. That returns the object value. example it will give you something like this "System.Data.DataRowView". So that condition never comes true.

that's all i can see from your code.